# In an orchestration pattern how to get domain contraints from another service?

Tags: microservices, orchestration

Theoretically in an orchestration pattern in microservices in it's purest form no service to service communication is allowed but rather all the micro services talk using the orchestration layer in between.

Practically if I want to get some domain info from serviceA to parse it in serviceB (read) is it ok to call directly the service or should I again try to pass that info from the orchestration layer?